# Find the range of the function given by $f(x)=\sqrt {16-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the range of the function given by $f(x)=\sqrt {16-x^2}$.

My Attempt:
$$f(x)=\sqrt {16-x^2}$$
$$y=\sqrt {16-x^2}$$
Squaring both sides, 
$$y^2=16-x^2$$

How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $f(x)\in \Bbb R$, we must have:

$$16-x^2\ge 0 \to (x-4)(x+4)\le0\to-4\le x \le 4$$

We also have that $16-x^2$ is continuous on that interval and the maximum is $16$ (when $x=0$) then $0\le 16-x^2\le 16$, so

$$0\le f(x)\le 4 $$

Comment: why is $16-x^2 \geq 0$?

Comment: Otherwise the square root won't be defined. (Talking about $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @Arnaldo, So how is $-4\leq x\leq 4$?

Comment: @Arnaldo, No, I don't know.

Comment: @LeonhardEuler: So just see that if you take $x>4$ or $x<-4$ you will get $x^2 > 16$ and then $\sqrt{16-x^2}$ will not be a real number.

Comment: The domain of definition of $f(x)$ is clearly $[-4,4]$ because we must ensure that what is under the $\sqrt{}$ is not negative.

Comment: @Arnaldo, Could you please helo me with these 2 questions sir?

1. math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211250/prove-that-the-relation-is-parallel-to-on-the-set-s-of-all-straight-lines-in



2. math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211523/show-that-the-function-f-n-to-n-given-by

Comment: @Arnaldo, I am going through it. If I get any difficulties in understanding, I will let you know! sir

Comment: @Arnaldo, sir what does it mean by "We also have that $16-x^2$ is continuois on that interval"?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler: It just mean that the graph doesn't have jumps. It helps us to make sure that $0\le 16-x^2\le 16$

Comment: @Arnaldo, How does one know that $16-x^2$ is continuous, without making a graph?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler: Because it is a polinomial. Any polinomial is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resort to the definition. The definition of the range of a function $g: X \to Y$ is the set $\{ y \in Y \mid y = f(x)\ \text{for some}\ x \in X \}$. Clearly the range of $g$ is a subset of $Y$, the codomain of $g$.

The function $f$ apparently has $[0, +\infty[$ as its codomain. Note that $x < -4$ or $x > 4$ implies that $f(x)$ is not meaningful; so the domain of $f$ can be at most $[-4, 4]$. Let $y \geq 0$. Note that $y = f(x)$ for some $-4 \leq x \leq 4$ if and only if $y^{2} = 16 - x^{2}$, if and only if $x^{2} = 16 - y^{2}$, and if and only if $x = \pm \sqrt{16 - y^{2}}$. Note that $y > 4$ implies that $\sqrt{16-y^{2}}$ is not meaningful. So $y = f(x)$ for some $-4 \leq x \leq 4$ if and only if $0 \leq y \leq 4$; so the range of $f$ is $[0,4]$.